# Как подключать плагины к проекту через Gulp?

Tags: javascript, gulp

Всем привет, в Гугле не нашел ответ на свой вопрос.

Подскажите как к проекту подключать js-плагины через Gulp. Например если я вижу на сайте такую конструкцию, то как ее подключить в проект?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ввести в консоль npm install sticky-sidebar - понятно, а дальше что? Буду благодарен за ответ, статью или видео на эту тему

Comment: а дальше смотри документацию как юзать. Например https://github.com/abouolia/sticky-sidebar

Answer (score 0):

Например так с помощью этого плагина https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat